# Uploading image to php server from android

Tags: php, android, image

This is my android client code which sends a file from the android gallery to the php server:

```
package com.example.upload;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgPath, fileName;
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    String urlServer = "http://url.com/abc.php";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;
    int serverResponseCode;
    String serverResponseMessage;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button load = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                // Start the Intent
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
            }
        });



    }

 // When Image is selected from Gallery
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgPath));
                Log.v("imgPath", imgPath);

                uploadImage();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Log.v("Error",e.toString());
        }

    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                try {
                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPath));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

                try
                {

                    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);

                    // Set HTTP method to POST.
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
                    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + imgPath +"\"" + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // Read file
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }

                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                    serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                    Log.v("Response Message",serverResponseMessage);

                    fileInputStream.close();
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Exception handling
                    Log.v("Error",ex.toString());
                }

                return serverResponseMessage;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful" + serverResponseCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
            }

        }.execute(null,null,null);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
$target_path  = "uploadedimages/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} 
else
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

I am trying to upload an image from my android client to the php server. The server response message gives me ok. The server status code also gives 200. So, A valid http connection is being built. Still, the image file does not get uploaded onto my domain. Logcat also does not log any error. I am confused as to where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a real url `http://vijetakarani.com/upload.php`?! if so, please remove it from your question otherwise you'll get hacked....

Comment: you're welcome, you should restrict the allowed file types on your php. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322137/php-file-upload-how-to-restrict-file-upload-type

Answer (score 0):

with respect to w3schools , this is my solution: 
use this code as php server side :

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
if ($check !== false) {
$uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
$uploadOk = 0;
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
$uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType !=         
"jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif"
 ) {
 $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 if ($uploadOk == 0) {
$this->response(['status' => "failed"]);
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo json_encode(['status' => "success", "filename" => 
   basename($_FILES["file"]["name"])]); 
    } else {
    $this->response(['status' => "failed"]);
    }
 }
 ?>
```

and in build.gradle file in repositories part under jcenter() add mavenCentral() like below:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
   }
}
```

and in app gradle add below lines:

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and add these permissions to manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and add below codes as activity_main.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context="ir.technopedia.myapplication.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_upload"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Upload" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and add this codes as MainActivity.java:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
ImageView img;
final int KeyGallery = 100, ReadExternalRequestCode = 200;
String url = "http://192.168.1.104/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean result = checkPermission(MainActivity.this);
            if (result)
                galleryIntent();
        }
    });

}

public void uploadImage(File file) {
    AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    try {
        params.put("file", file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    myClient.post(url + "android/upload.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                    Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                            .load(url + "android/uploads/" + jsonObject.getString("filename"))
                            .into(img);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), new String(responseBody), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            if (selectedImage != null) {
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                if (!filePathColumn.equals(null)) {
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    if (!picturePath.equals(null)) {
                        uploadImage(new File(picturePath));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), KeyGallery);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ReadExternalRequestCode:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                galleryIntent();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "permission problem!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}

public boolean checkPermission(final Context context) {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, ReadExternalRequestCode);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, ReadExternalRequestCode);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

this certainly work! enjoy...