# Limit users to upload only the specified file formats

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I managed to let users to upload files with format of pdf,doc and docx. However, users now upload files with any format. It doesn't stop them. They upload files with any format, but the program doesn't store them in the upload path. I want to strict them to ONLY upload those formats in my form and if the format is different, the program stops them. I put my code as extra reference:

```
 $config['upload_path'] = './media/resumes/';


  $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx';
    $config['max_size'] = '100000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload("myfile");           

        $file = $this->upload->data();
            $filename=$file['file_name'];
```

Looking forward for your answers

Comment: possibly you can check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322137/php-file-upload-how-to-restrict-file-upload-type

Answer (score 1):

you can use this when you are attaching files:

```
        <input type="file" name="userfile" id="fileAttachmentID" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx">
```

Comment: but still, he should validate it on server side. Client validation is not secure.

Comment: Thanks! It simply did it!