# WAMP restrict file upload for executable file

Tags: php, wamp

I am using wamp server .
I wrote a code where user could upload file and the uploaded file will be stored in the server for further processing .
I wanted to restrict the executable file upload to this API
so that only .feature files can be uploaded.
is there any way in WAMP server that we could restrict such file uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restrict your file types with your script. Don't need to do things on WAMP.

Please see the below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322137/php-file-upload-how-to-restrict-file-upload-type) for more info. It is explaining how to do it